# Figure de style de "C'est la reine des danses et la danse des reine" ?

Tags: figure-de-style

J'ai lu la phrase "la reine des danses et la danse des reines" dans la nouvelle *Menuet* de Maupassant, et en ai entendu une similaire aujourd'hui "la force des arguments et non les arguments de la force". Quelle est cette figure de style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est ce qu'on appelle **le chiasme<sup>1</sup>**, une figure de style du modèle ABBA, où AB est la première clause et BA est la deuxième clause (comme la première mais dans l'ordre inverse).

Il y a aussi des exemples en anglais, par exemple, la fameuse déclaration de JFK: “And so, my fellow Americans: ask not what your country can do for you—ask what you can do for your country.”

On le trouve dans de nombreuses langues, même les textes grecs et hébreux de la Bible.

---

There is chiasmus, a figure of speech of the model ABBA, where AB is the first clause and BA is the second clause (like the first but in reverse order).

There are also examples in English, for example, the famous statement of JFK: "And so, my fellow Americans: ask not what your country can do for 
you—ask what you can do for your country."

We find it in many languages, even the Greek and Hebrew texts of the Bible.

---

1. [Chiasmus (English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus) or [Le chiasme (français)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasme)

Comment: Merci pour la réponse, du coup quelle est la différence avec l'antimétabole dans la réponse Papa Poule ?

Comment: I think that chiasmus is more specific, whereas the other term is more general. I believe chiasmus is exactly what you're looking for, as it is a well known device in writing and rhetoric. (Je pense que le chiasme est plus spécifique que l'autre terme. Je crois que le chiasme est la terme exacte.)

Answer (score 1):

Il y a [**la métabole**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/metabole), qui  dans la rhétorique veut dire (d'après *CNRTL-TFLi*):

> Changement, soit dans les mots, soit dans les phrases.
>    − En partic.
>    ♦
>   ...
>   ♦ Procédé qui consiste à utiliser dans la seconde partie d'une
>   phrase des mots déjà utilisés dans la première partie, mais dans un
>   ordre différent, ce qui modifie le sens (d'apr. Dupr. 1980).

Par contre, *Wikipedia* parle de [l’**anti**métabole](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antim%C3%A9tabole) (littéralement: «répétition selon un ordre inversé») comme:

> une figure de style qui consiste en une répétition des mots
>   apparaissant en début de phrase en fin de celle-ci mais dans un ordre
>   différent comme dans l'expression «Il faut manger pour vivre et non
>   pas vivre pour manger».